# Is it possible to add the coverage report and code analysis for unit test projects in SonarQube? If so how should I configure them in SonarQube?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube, xunit, dotnet-test

I would like to add the code coverage report along with code analysis for my UnitTest project in SonarQube.

I had tried by adding the test files under 'sonar.test.inclusions' but the source files did not show any code coverage % nor the code smells

[Project Code Coverage Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htj5q.png)

Comment: SonarQube does not generate code-coverage; you need to provide them. See [heren](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770)

Comment: I have used opencover format to generate the code coverage result but for my unit test i'm unable to view the coverage lines nor the code smells